# How to change Background image of button on mouse click, created "Dynamically" ? - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I've created buttons dynamically, now unable to handle events on it, there is no usefull link on internet..

```
button.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button_MouseEnter);
button.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button_MouseLeave);

...

void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}


void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

This code is not working ...

Answer (score 0):

`MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` are respectively triggered when the mouse pointer hovers on and out of an object. The event you're searching for is `Click`.

Other than that, your code should work:

```
button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(button_Click);

void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.RoutedEventHanlder'

Comment: @Khateeb What is the issue now?

Comment: I just want to change image when it is Focused/Captured/Pressed

Comment: Come back to it's original state when it is released

Comment: @Khateeb Then use the events `MouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` rather than `Click`

Answer (score 0):

Try the MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonUp events. Change the image to the new one in MouseLeftButtonDown and change it back with MouseLeftButtonUp.

Comment: Define "not happening". Are the events not firing? Are the events firing but the images aren't changing? Have you set breakpoints in the events to see what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

So simple, just put this code as it is.

```
button.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button_MouseEnter);
button.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button_MouseLeave);


void button_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var brush = new ImageBrush();
     brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/camBlue.png", UriKind.Relative));
     Button1.Background = brush;
}


void button_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var brush = new ImageBrush();
     brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/camRed.png", UriKind.Relative));
     Button1.Background = brush;
}
```